# Find the number unsorted

Tags: arrays, sorting

### Find the unsorted/misplaced number

There is a sorted array *(say: `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]`)*.

Now, some number *(say: `-2`)* is inserted "by mistake" *(say: `[1, 2, 3, 4, -2, 5, 6, 7]`)*.

How would one got about finding such misplaced number?

Comment: what is your question whether it is about finding the misplaced number or placing it at the correct position ?

Comment: [1, 2, 3, 4, -2, 5, 6, 7], [1, 2, 3, 4, 33333, 5, 6, 7], [7, 6, 5, 4, 0, 3, 2, 1],  [7, 6, 5, 4,33333, 3, 2, 1]these four basic scenario.not difficult, but you need deal with a lot of possibilitis.

Comment: Just finding the number is enough ? or you want to place it in correct position in the array ? If an array has misplaced element, how can you call it a sorted array ?

Comment: Check http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort  for sorting an array

Answer (score 0):

If one number is unsorted then it's quite simple.

For every number other than the first, if it's less than the preceding number, it's out of order.

Pseudo-code for such a beast would be something like:

```
def findIndexOfFirstOutOfOrderElement(list):
    for index in 2 to list.last inclusive:
        if list[index] < list[index-1]:
            return index
    return -1
```

That will give you the index of the *first* out-of-order element or `-1` if the entire list is sorted correctly.

If you want to find others, either fix the one at that index and then call the function again (until you get `-1`), or modify the function to handle that requirement - I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use like below:

Assume var list = [1,2,3,4,-2,5,6,7];

for(var i = 1; i < list.length; i++) {

```
    if(list[i] < list[i-1]){
        return list[i];
    }
```

}

Remind variable i start from 1, otherwise it will be out of range.

Answer (score -1):

public class HelloWorld{

```
 public static void main(String []args){
    int a[]= {1,2,3,4,-2,5,6};

    for(int i=0; i < a.length-1; i++){
        if(a[i] < a[i+1]){
            //
        } else {
            System.out.print(a[i+1]);
            break;
        }
    }
 }
```

}

This code will print first unsorted number.